# Eclipse for C/C++ closes as soon as I open

Tags: c, eclipse

I have Eclipse for java on my laptop aswell as the most recent jdk and jre, all of this works fine. I have recently started C programming and downloaded the C version of eclipse. I then copied the file from downloads to my own directory. The problem is that when I try and open eclipse the splash screen shows up for half a second then disappears, eclipse then doesnt open. How can I fix this? I have found people with similar problems but none of their solutions work for me.

**Note:** I also have the C compiler: Fortran, C and C++ for Windows downloaded in the same directory as my eclipse folder if that matters.

Comment: I have tried re-installing with no success

Answer (score 2):

Try a couple of things.

- Uninstall and reinstall Eclipse.
- Make sure you have the latest version of Java and JDK. Eclipse needs Java to run.
- Sometimes, having multiple versions of java can also cause problems so uninstall unnecessary and old versions of java.
- Also make sure that Java Home location is added to the environmental path variable.

One of these solutions should fix the problem. Hope this helps :)

Comment: ThankS I'll try those